# Can I save the old value of a reactive object when it changes?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shiny-reactivity

**Note:** After coming up with the answer I reworded the question to make if clearer.

Sometimes in a `shiny` app. I want to make use of a value selected by the user for a widget, as well as the previous value selected for that same widget. This could apply to reactive values derived from user input, where I want the old and the new value.

The problem is that if I try to save the value of a widget, then the variable containing that value has to be reactive or it will not update every time the widget changes. But, if I save the the value in a reactive context it will always give me the current value, not the previous one.

How can I save the previous value of a widget, but still have it update every time the user changes the widget?

Is there a way that does not require the use of an `actionButton` every time the user changes things? Avoiding an `actionButton` can be desirable with adding one is otherwise unnecessary and creates excess clicking for the user.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Thanks - I have edited the question and ended up figuring out my own answer. The question no longer has code.

Comment: Can't you use a global variable, defined before `server`? Then inside server, store values into this global variable with `<<-`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seeing as the session flush event method seems to be broken for this purpose, here is an alternative way to do it using an `observeEvent` construct and a reactive variable.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Memory"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("val", "Next Value", 10)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("curval"),
      verbatimTextOutput("lstval")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(lstval=0,curval=0)

  observeEvent(input$val, {rv$lstval <- rv$curval; rv$curval <- input$val})

  curre <- reactive({req(input$val);  input$val; rv$curval})
  lstre <- reactive({req(input$val);  input$val; rv$lstval})

  output$curval <- renderPrint({sprintf("cur:%d",curre())})
  output$lstval <- renderPrint({sprintf("lst:%d",lstre())})
}
options(shiny.reactlog = TRUE)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "global variable" here? You do not seem to define anything in `gloabl.r`.

Comment: Yeah, a sloppy but common use of the term "global variable". Corrected it.

Comment: Err, turns out you don't need to use that `<<-` operator if you use a reactive variable. Cool. Thanks for prodding me.

Comment: I think the `observeEvent` / `reactiveValues` approach is definitely the way to go now.

Answer (score 9):

**Update** This answer was posted before the advent of the `reactiveValues`/`observeEvent` model in `shiny`. I think that @MikeWise 's answer is the better way to do this.

After some playing around this is what I came up with. The ui.r is nothing special

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId="XX", label="Choose a letter",choices=letters[1:5])
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("Current"),
      textOutput("old")
    )
  ) 
))
```

`"Current"` will  display the current selection and `"old"` displays the previous selection.

In the `server.r` I made use of three key functions: `reactiveValues`, `isolate` and `session$onFlush`.

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  Values<-reactiveValues(old="Start")

  session$onFlush(once=FALSE, function(){
    isolate({ Values$old<-input$XX })
  })


  output$Current <- renderText({paste("Current:",input$XX)})

  output$old <- renderText({ paste("Old:",Values$old) })
}
```

The `server.r` works like this.

First, `Values$old` is created using the `reactiveValues` function. I gave it the value "Start" to make it  clear what was happening on load up.

Then I added a `session$onFlush` function. Note that I have `session` as an argument in my `server` function. This will run every time that shiny flushes the reactive system - such as when the `selectizeInput` is changed by the user. What is important is that it will run before `input$XX` gets a new value - so the value has changed at the `selectizeInput` but not at `XX`.

Inside the `session$onFlush` I then assign the outgoing value of `XX` to `Values$old`. This is done inside an `isolate()` as this will prevent any problems with `input$XX` gets updated with the new values. I can then use `input$XX` and `Values$old` in the `renderText()` functions.

Comment: It seems the script does not work. I got the same value for Old and Current.

Comment: Broken. Looks like something essential for this to work was changed.

Comment: @MikeWise Thanks, This was written pre `observeEvent` so it is out of date now.